How do I set a placeholder attribute on a text input in React?
I am new to React and am building out a text input atom. I want to be able to set a placeholder as a prop. If the placeholder prop is empty I want no attribute to show (no point having an empty placeholder attribute. However, I have not been able to figure this out.
I have tried various methods including a ternary operator as such:
let placeholderAttr = placeholder ? `placeholder="${placeholder}"`: '';

return (
     <div className={['text-field', `text-field-${size}`, statusStylesInput].join(' ')}>
        <input type="text" {placeholderAttr}></input>
      </div>
)

But this doesn't work. I can set the attribute directly, like:
 <input type="text" placeholder={placeholder}></input>

But if the placeholder prop is empty it still renders the empty placeholder attribute, eg:
<input type="text" placeholder></input>

Does anyone know the best way to go about this?

If the placeholder prop is empty, what text do you want to show?

I guess you could do {...(placeholder ? { placeholder } : {}}, but that seems like a lot to "solve" what isn't really a problem.

You're picking a fight with React here. I wouldn't worry about an empty attribute like this in the slightest. The Browser treats no placeholder attribute, placeholder, and placeholder="" exactly the same, its not like a checked attribute or anything like that.

With possible values being undefined, null, "" etc. i'd use const finalPlaceholder = useMemo(()=>(!placeholder?undefined:placeholder,[placeholder]). The finalPlaceholder can then be assigned to the placeholder prop. If it's filled with actual text you will see it otherwise "undefined" will be linked to placeholder resulting in the property not being rendered.

You can do something like this:
const TextInput = ({ placeholder, size, statusStylesInput }) => {
  return (
    <div className={['text-field', `text-field-${size}`, statusStylesInput].join(' ')}>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        {...(placeholder ? { placeholder } : {})} 
      />
    </div>
  );
};

